# Eigen remove for in plane line(s) intersection method

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, eigen

I'm trying to do a [plane line(s) intersection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line%E2%80%93plane_intersection) method using Eigen. The code works, but I want to remove the for loop (used to process each point). The goal is to make this method run as fast as possible.

- Input: planeNormal, planePoint, linesP0 (3xN), linesp1 (3xN)
- Output: intersetcionsPoints (3xN)
- Number of points is N

Complete code:

```
void PlaneLineIntersect(const Vector3f &planeNormal, const Vector3f &planeP0, const Matrix3Xf &linesP0, const Matrix3Xf &linesP1, Matrix3Xf &I, float &t)
{   
    Matrix3Xf p0l0(linesP0.rows(), linesP0.cols());
    // ################################
    // ## HOW TO REMOVE THIS FOR (colwise?) ##
    for (int i = 0; i < linesP0.cols(); i++)
    {
        float denom = planeNormal.dot(linesP1.col(i) - linesP0.col(i));
        if (denom > 1e-6 || denom < -1e-6)          // há uma interseção
        {
            Vector3f p0l0 = planeP0 - linesP0.col(i);
            t = p0l0.dot(planeNormal) / denom;
            p0l0 = (t * (linesP1.col(i) - linesP0.col(i))) + linesP0.col(i);
            I.col(i) = p0l0;
        }
    }
}

int main(cli::array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    int n = 1000;
    Eigen::Vector3f planeNormal = Eigen::Vector3f(0, 0, -1);
    Eigen::Vector3f planeP0 = Eigen::Vector3f(0, 0, 7);
    Eigen::Matrix3Xf linesP0 = Matrix3Xf::Random(3, n);
    Eigen::Matrix3Xf linesP1 = Matrix3Xf::Random(3, n);
    Eigen::Matrix3Xf I = Matrix3Xf::Zero(3, n);
    float t;

    high_resolution_clock::time_point t1 = high_resolution_clock::now();

#pragma omp parallel for
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        PlaneLineIntersect(planeNormal, planeP0, linesP0, linesP1, I, t);

    high_resolution_clock::time_point t2 = high_resolution_clock::now();
    double duration = (double) (duration_cast<microseconds>(t2 - t1).count());
    cout << "\nTempo total = " << duration / 1000 << " ms" << endl;
    cout << "\nTempo / ponto = " << duration / (n * 100) << " us\n" << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
```

}

Comment: The calculation of `denom` would essentially just be `RowVectorXf denom = planeNormal.transpose() * (linesP1 - linesP0);` For the rest: what do you want `I` to be at columns where `abs(denom)<=1e-6`?

Comment: @chtz We are almost solving this, we are stuck at one code line, can you take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42935944/multiplication-of-each-matrix-column-by-each-vector-element-using-eigen-c-libr