# C++ Eigen Library: Mutliplying vector with elements from row vector

Tags: c++, matrix, eigen, matrix-multiplication

I am trying to obtain a matrix consisting of the product between a vector and respective elements from a row vector like this:

```
Eigen::Vector3f vec;
vec << 1,
       2,
       3;

Eigen::RowVectorXf val;
val.setLinSpaced(5, 1, 5); //val = [1,2,3,4,5]

//result should be
//1,2,3,4,5
//2,4,6,8,10
//3,6,9,12,15
```

After seeing [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42935944/multiplication-of-each-matrix-column-by-each-vector-element-using-eigen-c-libr/42937353), I have tried

```
val.array().colwise()*vec.array()
```

and

```
vec.array().rowwise()*val.array()
```

but they just don't work.

val is a 1xn vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want a standard matrix product:

```
MatrixXf res = vec * val;
```