# Multiply two Eigen vectors by corresponding elements

Tags: c++, eigen

I have two Eigen vectors (`vectorOne` and `vectorTwo`) of my defined type( see below for my type).

```
typedef Matrix<double, 50, 1> myVector;
```

I want a third vector `vectorThree` that will have multiplication of vectorOne and vectorTwo. But I want to multiply each element by corresponding element - i.e. vectorOne(i, 0) by vectorTwo (i, 0) so that I have something like below for all i.

> vectorThree (i, 0) = vectorOne(i, 0) * vectorTwo(i, 0)

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42935944/multiplication-of-each-matrix-column-by-each-vector-element-using-eigen-c-libr#) and tried `vectorOne.array() * vectorTwo.array()` but it did not work.

I know I can do that using a for loop and iterating over all elements. But is there a more efficient or built in Eigen function for that?

Comment: What about [`std::inner_product`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/inner_product)? Or you can choose [`std::valarray`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/valarray) instead?

Comment: "but it did not work" what exactly did not work and in what way did it fail?

Comment: What "did not work" in array approach? Did not compile? You have got zero initialized array?

Answer (score 4):

1. You should be able to cast matrices to arrays via `.array()` and multiply it here. It would return an array expression though, so maybe it is not what you want.

From [Eigen documentation](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialArrayClass.html):

> First of all, of course you can multiply an array by a scalar, this works in the same way as matrices. Where arrays are fundamentally different from matrices, is when you multiply two together. Matrices interpret multiplication as matrix product and **arrays interpret multiplication as coefficient-wise product**. Thus, two arrays can be multiplied if and only if they have the same dimensions.

2. Otherwise you can use `.cwiseProduct` of matrix to get matrix as result.
   https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__QuickRefPage.html#matrixonly

Answer (score 1):

You can take advantage of asDiagonal() feature in Eigen library.

https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1MatrixBase.html#title15

So, for your case:

```
vectorOne.asDiagona()*vectorTwo
```

Should do the job.

Remember: "This is only for vectors (either row-vectors or column-vectors), i.e. matrices which are known at compile-time to have either one row or one column."